# Faild to resolve all of androidx dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, dependencies, androidx

I downloaded the 'BasicSample' project from below link and add to Android Studio, but when i sync the project, show error about failed to resolve all of 'androidx' dependencies.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample

I searched and try something, like remove .idea folder or invalidate cache and restart and add 'android.useAndroidX=true' and 'android.enableJetifier=true' to 'gradle.properties' but not worked and i get same errors.

Errors is in below:

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.2.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.2.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0

Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0

Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
Install Repository and sync project

Failed to resolve: androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0

Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0

Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0

Failed to resolve: androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06

Failed to resolve: androidx.test:runner:1.1.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.test:rules:1.1.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06

Failed to resolve: androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1

Failed to resolve: androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
```

How to fix these errors?

Comment: Nobody help me? I should to solve problem :(

Comment: can you post your gradle code

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

But also when you pass imports below (without androidx)

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-rc1"
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
```

You will be able to import [image]
 among other `androidx.*` imports. Give it a try and give feed back!

But for imports like `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders` you will have to pass 
`implementation group: 'androidx.lifecycle', name: 'lifecycle-extensions', version: '2.0.0-rc01'`